# SignalR Clients.All.function_name(); not working

Tags: signalr.client

Forgive my bad english. 
I have a project that contains signalR and JavaScript code. But the controller side called Clients.All.function_name (); not working.

**My hub class:**

```
public class yenile : Hub
{ 
   public void sayfaYenile()
   {
       Clients.All.syenile();
   }
}
```

**My javascript code:**

```js
<script>
    var sayfayenile = $.connection.yenile;
    sayfayenile.client.syenile = $(function () {
       $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: '/hasta/',
             data: {},
             success: function (data) {
                $("#con").html($(data).find("#con").html());
             },
        }
        });
     });
     $.connection.hub.start().done(function () { console.log("connected"); });
</script>
```

**IHubContext**

```
public static IHubContext yenileContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<yenile>();
```

**And calling the yenileContext**

```
yenileContext.Clients.All.yenile();
```

**My Startup class:**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly you must refer signalr library files.Depend on your signlar verions you should change.

```
<!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" ></script>
<!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Second point: Your javascript reference must use camel case for calling your server class and its members function.

Comment: The SignalR library files were added just above the JavaScript code. But it still does not work

Comment: did you use camel case in your javascript  function

Comment: Client function gives a "No further information on this object could be discovered" error

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the error.
sayfayenile.client.syenile = $(function () instead of 
sayfayenile.client.yenile = $(function ()